# unable to write powershell command output to variable

Tags: variables, firefox, powershell, scripting

All i am trying to find if firefox is blocked or not in a system. I have imported module from remy's website http://code.remyservices.net/powershell-firefoxpref/wiki/Home .

Thanks to remy for his invaluable help. I am able to get the output in command.But i am not able to assign the output to a variable. Please help. Below is the code of the script and the output...

code:

```
Import-Module 'C:\firefox module\FirefoxPref.psd1'

Import-Module 'C:\firefox module\FirefoxPref.psm1'

Get-Firefoxpref -scope user -file mozilla.cfg -setting network.proxy.type
```

output in powershell:

```
Setting found:
    lockPref("network.proxy.type", 2);
```

I would like to assign the output to a variable.

```
$var = powershell .\firefox block proxy.ps1
```

is also not working..

Comment: Why do you open another powershell session with `powershell`? Is the code you provided in the file `proxy.ps1`? Have you tried to just use `$var = proxy.ps1`? Sorry, I don't know anything about that firefox module. Also try to search SO for something like "Assign out to variable [powershell]"

Comment: Actually my requirement is to write a powershell script to check if mozilla.cfg is having a specific value lockpref(Network.proxy.type,2) if so, it proves me that firefox proxy settings are blocked.

After importing firefox module, i run a command to check if the above value is present. Then i tried to assign it to a variable. But that's not happening. So i thought of assigning the output of the .ps1 to a variable.. No luck so far....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developer has used write-host in the script. Following is the snip:

```
if ($SettingFound -eq 0) {Write-Host "Setting found:"}
Write-Host "   "$_
```

Replace **Write-Host** with **Write-Output** and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Surely just use:

```
$Var = Get-Firefoxpref -scope user -file mozilla.cfg -setting network.proxy.type
```

I have not used this module before but it shouldn't be massively different to not store its output.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Automatic_Mozilla_Configurator/Locked_config_settings 

This will only work if the machines are all setup to use a CFG file, obviously. For me the statement returns nothing as we only have policies here for IE as we don't support Mozilla/Chrome etc.

Comment: You are correct. I have a CFG file configured to disable Firefox proxy settings. And i want read the content and decide disabled or not...

Comment: $Var = Get-Firefoxpref -scope user -file mozilla.cfg -setting network.proxy.type

gives me the output directly... nothing getting saved in $Var...

Answer (score 0):

Finally after modifying the Firefox Module here is my script to check if mozill.cfg present, if present whether the proxy is blocked or not...

$strFileName="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\mozilla.cfg"

Function proxy-Check {

```
Import-Module '\\firefox module\FirefoxPref.psd1'

Import-Module '\\firefox module\FirefoxPref.psm1'

$Var = Get-Firefoxpref -scope user -file mozilla.cfg -setting network.proxy.type

if ($var) {

$str = "Compliant"

} else {

$str = "Non-compliant"

}

Return, $str

}
```

If (Test-path $strFileName) {

```
proxy-Check

}else{

Write-host "Firefox Not installed"

}
```

Thanks a lot to user4221907 :) :) :) :)